# Directories last file name display only

Tags: c#

I am simply showing file names from folder in a text block one by one every time i click on button. But it directly gives the last file name from directory.Any suggestions please.

**C#**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Folder);
    string startWithThis = text.Text.ToUpper();
    string files = "";
    lstFiles = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in allFiles)
    {
        string file = s.Replace(Folder, string.Empty);
        if (file.ToUpper().StartsWith(startWithThis))
        {
            lstFiles.Add(file);
            text.Text = lstFiles.ElementAt(i);
            i++;
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing the problem -

```
text.Text = lstFiles.ElementAt(i);
```

you are actually replacing all the contents of the text box with the current file name

replace it with -

```
text.Text = text.Text + lstFiles.ElementAt(i);
```

OR if you need the each file name in new line -

```
text.Text = text.Text + Environment.NewLine + lstFiles.ElementAt(i);
```

This will display all the files in single click.
Now if you need to display just a file name on every click additionally, you can do maintain a `List<string>` as list of all the files in the folder as public variable, next on every click just append your text box with the next item from this list

Comment: This will show all the items on single click. What i want is every time i click on button it shows next file.

Comment: @AnoushaKhan - Edited the answer

Comment: @AnoushaKhan: As a suggestion to your problem you can populate the list of file in method other than `ButtonClick`, and keep a `public` `static` variable for button click counter, next in `ButtonClick` just append the text box with list item index as per counter.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path));
foreach (var dir in dirs)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
}
```

I use this piece of code right now to fill a combobox with directory names. If you replace comboBox1 with your textblock name it should work.

Comment: No i dont want items in combobox. I want items to be shown one by one after each click.

Answer (score 1):

You should *combine* not *rewrite* the names; a simple amendment is

```
  text.Text += ", " + lstFiles.ElementAt(i);
```

A better approach is to use *Linq*:

```
  var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(Folder)
    .Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file))
    .Where(name => name.StartsWith(startWithThis, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

  text.Text = String.Join(", ", files);

  myComboBox.Items.AddRange(files.ToArray());
```